ggplot2 apply geom_smooth() to each individual participant across factor levels
I have data where n participants have measures across 3 "bouts" within 2 "conditions. I want to produce a graph where I have a geom_smooth() across bout for each individual participant for each level of condition. There should be n * 2 separate lines and lines should be coloured by condition (no need to identify participants between conditions).
I have this R code that pools participants within condition:
ggplot(data, aes(bout, y, colour = condition)) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F)


And this R code that pools condition within each participant:
ggplot(data, aes(bout, y, colour = condition)) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(aes(group = participant), method = "lm", se = F)


Essentially, I want to combine these to have n pink lines for control condition and n green lines for experimental condition.

If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from dput() or reprex::reprex() and any libraries you are using. Check it out: making R reproducible questions.

aes(..., color = condition, group = interaction(condition, participant))?  (or ...paste(condition,participant)

Please share data. Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of dput(data). Or, if the data set is too big with the output of dput(head(data, 20)).

Including some example data with dput or using a common toy dataset in your question would be helpful. The data here is easy to recreate so here is an example using interaction which makes a factor out of some set of variables pasted together.
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(
  y = c(
    sort(rnorm(120, 150, 20)),
    sort(rnorm(120, 120, 15))
  ),
  bout = c(
    rep(1:3, each = 40),
    rep(1:3, each = 40)
  ),
  condition = rep(c("ctrl", "exp"), each = 120),
  participant = c(
    rep(1:40, times = 3),
    rep(1:40, times = 3)
  )
)
ggplot(data, aes(bout, y, colour = condition)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = interaction(condition, participant)),
     method = "lm", se = F, linewidth = 0.5)


